# Commons Validator， how change the message of NumberFormatException

Tags: java, spring, validation

[image]

i want to change the message of NumberFormatException. please tell me how should i do.
thank you.

Comment: Could you please post a code example - how do you validate your number?

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15143839/

Comment: I guess this should be closed as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104012/how-to-customize-default-message-for-bigdecimal ...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize default message for BigDecimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104012/how-to-customize-default-message-for-bigdecimal)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, catch exception in controller and set appropriate error message (in this case your custom message) in request. In view, check if error message exists in request, show it int view.

Controller :

```
    try{
     //your logic goes here
    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
   request.setAttribute("ERROR_MSG" , " YOUR CUSTOMER MESSAGE GOES HERE");
}
```

JSP:

check if error msg is present in request object, add this message to text tooltip.

Alternatively if you are using Struts, make use of ActionErrors